# How to get all substrings beetwen markers from strings. JAVA

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with geting substrings from string.
I want to find all substrings beetwen markers "F2*" and "K" from my string.

```
String str = "F2* *KF2*AT+BCAST:07,Max2*KF2*AT+JN*K";
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
                                        Pattern.quote("F2*")
                                        + "(.*?)"
                                        + Pattern.quote("*K")
                               ).matcher(str);
            while(m.find()){
                String match = m.group(1);
               Toast.makeText(this,  "Contains frame: " +match , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

my expectation is:
"  ", "AT+BCAST:07,Max2", "AT+JN"

It doesn't work. 
If it will work, next step is to remove all frame "F2*....*K" from string.
I want to do this by:

```
 str.replaceFirst(temp1, "");
```

where temp1 contanis F2* + match + *K

It is correct?

Thanks in advance,

@Melih Altıntaş, thanks for answer.

It doesn't work in my android application. Matcher.find() is always false and without it java reports with no successful match.

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
MainString  = "F2* *KF2*AT+BCAST:07,Max2*KF2*AT+JN*K";
    Toast.makeText(this,  MainString , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
     if(    (MainString.contains("F2*"))&&(MainString.contains("*K"))  )
     { 
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=F2\\*).*?(?=\\*K)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(MainString);
            Toast.makeText(this,  "contains frame" + matcher.group(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // this only for cheking error - > java reports no successful match

            while (matcher.find()) {            
                Toast.makeText(this,  "zawiera ramke: " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println(matcher.group());

            }

     }
    }catch(Exception e){
           Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: try using group(2), I don't think regex is 0 based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If F2* and *K are always the terms you are looking for there is no need to use regex if that's not working for you. You can do this with indexof, you just have to repeat the process. I'm assusimg by the way that START_KEY always preceeds END_KEY and that these are not duplicated by the normal text you want to extract in this process.

```
private static final String START_KEY = "F2*";
private static final String END_KEY = "*K";
List<String> substrings = new ArrayList<String>();

private void processString(String s){
    if(s.indexof(START_KEY) == -1){
        return;
    }

    //Offset target string by number of char in START_KEY
    substrings.add(s.substr(s.indexof(START_KEY) + 3, s.indexOf(END_KEY)));

    //Recursive call on left over char if any exist
    try{
        processString(s.substr(endKey + 2);  
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //ignore - if no string left call should end
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i didn`t know about it. This is my first quation at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can search the frames using `java.lang.String#indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` and subsequently starting from the position where you found the "K".

Comment: That only works if there's a single K in the string. If there are 2 K's indexof is not a good idea.

Comment: Why? You search the first frame through `indexOf("F2", 0)` and `indexOf("K", 0)` and at subsequent searches, replace the "0" with the position of the last K found - so that every new search starts after the last K has been found.

Comment: Only searching for K doesn't deal with the starting marker. Just the end. Index of works if you look for both and continue looking after chopping off the found string.

Comment: This is simply not true, you can provide a start index for `indexOf` at which position the search should start (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) so that you don't *have* to chop up the string.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You look for K, substing what comes before upto the end of the F2* and then continue from the end of K. I did not realize you could indexof after a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

to find between F2* and *k ==>

```
    String str = "F2* *KF2*AT+BCAST:07,Max2*KF2*AT+JN*K";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=F2\\*).*?(?=\\*K)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {            
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

output :

```
1 
2 AT+BCAST:07,Max2
3 AT+JN
```

if you want only remove from string ==>

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=F2\\*).*?(?=\\*K)", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

output:

```
F2**KF2**KF2**K
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my android application. Matcher.find() is always false and without it java reports with no successful match.